# Get values from PHP array

Tags: php, for-loop

I created a foreach loop in PHP like this:

```
foreach( $value as $element_content => $content ) {

  $canvas_elements = "<div id='" . $element_id . "'>" . $content . "</div>";  
  $elements[] = $canvas_elements;

}
```

So I get the values in a PHP array like this:

```
print_r($elements);
```

But this gives the results:

```
Array ( [0] =>
Text to edit
[1] =>
Text to edit
)
```

But I only want this output and not Array ( [0] => etc:

```
<div id="element_id1"></div>
<div id="element_id2"></div>
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with the array, if you want nothing but echo/print out some markup:

```
foreach( $value as $element_content => $content )
{
    echo "<div id='" . $element_id . "'>" . $content . "</div>";  
}
```

Whill do, however, if you insist on using that array:

```
echo implode('', $elements);
```

turns the array into a string, just like you wanted it to. Your using `print_r` is not the way forward, as it's more of a debug function: [check the docs](http://www.php.net/print_r)

> Prints human-readable information about a variable

Just a little detail: you don't seem to be declaring `$elements` as an array anywhere. PHP will create a new variable, and assign it an empty array for you, true enough, but if you change your ini settings to `E_STRICT | E_ALL`, you'll notice that it doesn't do this without complaining about it. (and rrightfully so)
It's always better to declare and initialize your variables beforehand. writing `$elements = array();` isn't hard, nor is it very costly. At any rate it's less costly than producing a notice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used your last method and works exactly as a would like!!

Comment: @Kim: You're welcome, though I must say: avoid the array, if at all possible. If you can't avoid it, do consider my (slightly pedantic) side-note at the bottom: _always_ declare and initialize variables beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<?php 
 $data = array('a'=>'apple','b'=>'banana','c'=>'orange');
 $string = implode("<br/>", $data);
 ?>
<pre><?php print_r($string); ?></pre>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
apple
banana
orange
```

Answer (score 0):

[print_r($array)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is a function to display the value of the variable to the user. it's created for debugging purposes. If you want to have a HTML output, please use "echo" or something particular.

```
foreach( $value as $element_content => $content ) {
    echo "<div id='" . $element_id . "'>" . $content . "</div> \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$elements = array();
foreach( $value as $element_content => $content ) {
    $canvas_elements = "<div id='" . $element_id . "'>" . $content . "</div>"; 
    $elements[] = $canvas_elements;
}
echo $mergedStrArray = implode("\n", $elements);
```

Can you try for me, Does it work?